# How to call python library from the web browser installed for “user1” through php

Tags: python, apache2, php, libraries

I am working on the project where I am calling python code from the PHP in ubuntu. The python code is using the library "pytesseract" which is included in the import. I have installed the python library "pytesseract" for the "user1" but when I run the PHP file from a web browser, then web browser could not access the python library "pytesseract" installed for user1. Is there any way to give the absolute/relative path of the library in the python so that root or any other user could execute it in linux?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking for. Do you want to use Python library in your PHP code? Or do you want to execute a command of a Python library with PHP? or is it something completely different?

Comment: I want to execute python code through PHP. but when I run the PHP file from the browser, then it shows an error that library used in python that is 
"pytesseract" not found. Because apache user could not find the library as the library is installed for the local user "User1"